# Binary Search Tree Recursion without a node struct

Tags: c, recursion, search, malloc, binary-search-tree

I have to get a project done for university but I can't figure out how it can be done.

The problem is that I want to build a binary search tree application with the following given functions. I need to build some kind of recursion but my problem is that the **bst_insert(tree *bst, int key)** function takes a **tree** as an input and not a node. So my idea which I have written below (**bst_insert(bst->root_node->left, key);**) does not work.

Does someone have an idea what I could do to get a solution that works?

Thank you a lot!!!

Here is a part of my Header file (tree.h)

```
    typedef struct node {
      int key;
      struct node *left;
      struct node *right;
    } node;

    typedef struct tree {
      node *root_node;
      int (*compare_keys)(int x, int y);
    } tree;

    void bst_insert(tree *bst, int key);
```

Here is a part of the tree.c file

```
void init(tree *bst) {
  bst->root_node = 0;
  bst->compare_keys = 0;
}

void bst_insert(tree *bst, int key) {    
  if (bst->root_node == NULL) {
    bst->root_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    bst->root_node->key = key;
    bst->root_node->left = NULL;
    bst->root_node->right = NULL;
  }
  else {
    if (key < bst->root_node->key) {
      bst_insert(bst->root_node->left, key);
    }
    if (key > bst->root_node->key) {
      bst_insert(bst->root_node->right, key);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You clearly have a disagreement with whoever specified the project. You should probably talk to them.

Comment: "function takes a tree as an input and not a node" - and that's the convention.

Comment: Why don't you change `bst_insert` to take a node?

Comment: @4386427 i am not allowed to change this line of code "void bst_insert(tree *bst, int key)"

Comment: @TheoG - But you are allowed to change everything inside the function, right ?

Comment: @4386427 exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you were allowed to, passing `bst->root_node->left` directly is not going to work. Function arguments are passed by value, and the recursive call may need to change the value of `bst->root_node->left` (if it's `NULL`).

If you want a function `f` to be able to change a variable `x`, the easiest solution is to have `f` take a pointer and call it as `f(&x)` (passing the address of `x`). We can apply that to your recursive insert function:

```
void bst_insert(node **ppnode, int key) {    
    if (*ppnode == NULL) {
        *ppnode = malloc(sizeof **ppnode);
        (*ppnode)->key = key;
        (*ppnode)->left = NULL;
        (*ppnode)->right = NULL;
    }
    else if (key < (*ppnode)->key) {
        bst_insert(&(*ppnode)->left, key);
    }
    else if (key > (*ppnode)->key) {
        bst_insert(&(*ppnode)->right, key);
    }
}
```

This code would work, but as you say, it has the wrong type.

That's not a big problem, however: We can simply rename this function and provide a wrapper with the right name and type.

```
static void bst_node_insert(node **ppnode, int key) {    
    if (*ppnode == NULL) {
        *ppnode = malloc(sizeof **ppnode);
        (*ppnode)->key = key;
        (*ppnode)->left = NULL;
        (*ppnode)->right = NULL;
    }
    else if (key < (*ppnode)->key) {
        bst_node_insert(&(*ppnode)->left, key);
    }
    else if (key > (*ppnode)->key) {
        bst_node_insert(&(*ppnode)->right, key);
    }
}

void bst_insert(tree *bst, int key) {
    bst_node_insert(&bst->root_node, key);
}
```

The structure of this code mirrors the structure of your data types: You have a `tree` containing a pointer to a `node`, which contains pointers to itself. Similarly, the tree insert function `bst_insert` contains a call to the node insert function `bst_node_insert`, which contains calls to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that you can't change the definition of `bst_insert`, I think the solution is to make a new temporary tree before calling the function. It feels a bit strange but something like the code below should work:

```
tree tempTree;
...
if (key < bst->root_node->key) {
  if (bst->root_node->left == NULL)
  {
      // Add a new node
      bst->root_node->left = malloc(sizeof(node));
      bst->root_node->left->key = key;
      bst->root_node->left->left = NULL;
      bst->root_node->left->right = NULL;
      return;
  }

  // Make a temporary tree for a recursive call
  tempTree.root_node = bst->root_node->left;
  tempTree.compare_keys = bst->compare_keys;
  bst_insert(&tempTree, key);
  return;
}
```

Further, I think you are doing something wrong in this line:

```
if (key < bst->root_node->key) {
```

I'm pretty sure that you are supposed to use the `compare_keys` function. Maybe like:

```
if (compare_keys(key, bst->root_node->key) < 0) {
```

Comment: That doesn't actually work. Try it: Your code never actually inserts anything into the tree the user calls it with.

Comment: @Melpomene - Right! That was wrong - thanks. Answer updated.

Comment: That's a lot of redundant code just to avoid `bst->root_node->left = tempTree.root_node;` afterwards.

Comment: @4386427 I think you are right with your idea to use compare_keys, but I don't understand the relation between the "compare_keys" in tree struct and another funtion which is in my tree.c file I haven't mentioned before: 

void init_with_comp_operator(tree *bst, int(*comp)(int x, int y)) {
  bst_init(bst);
  bst->compare_keys = comp;
}